# Склонение названий напитков

Tags: склонение

Стоит ли склонять названия напитков вроде "Джек Дэниэлс", "Мэйкерс Марк"? 
Я купил две бутылки "Мэйкерс Марк(а)"

Answer (score 1):

Если склонять, то оба слова. А вот можно ли не склонять, не знаю. Без родового слова — сомнительно.